# Can you specify the max-snippet length in a X-robots-tag header?

Tags: html, web-crawlers, http-headers, meta-robots

The specs by Google does not address this issue. So, I would like to know what is the x-robots-tag equivalent for:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="max-snippet:20"/>
```

Is it this:

```
X-robots-tag: googlebot: max-snippet:20
```